# Program for considering a word such as colour's as 2 words

Tags: python, regex, list, sys, pathlib

I would like my code to consider [colour's] as 2 words [colour] & [s] and take the count for it in python. I tried doing in this way but causes many errors

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import re

text_file = Path(sys.argv[1])

if text_file.exists() and text_file.is_file():
    read = text_file.read_text()
    length = len(read.split())
    addi = len(re.search(r'*.[["a-zA-Z"]]', text_file))
    length += addi
    print(f'{text_file} has', length, 'words')
else:
    print(f'File not found: {text_file}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the function `.split()` and `re.findall` for your purpose.. With the latter function, you could count the number of words (with [color's] as 2 words) instead of looking for the individual words in group. For example

```
import re

read = "today is Color's birthday"
print(read.split())
print(len(read.split()))

read2 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', read)
print(read2)
print(len(read2))
```

Output:

```
['today', 'is', "Color's", 'birthday']
4
['today', 'is', 'Color', 's', 'birthday']
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the apostrophe with some arbitrary whitespace character then count the length of the list created by *string.split()*

However, you may not want to replace all apostrophes. You almost certainly only want to replace apostrophes that are bounded by letters.

Therefore with a combination of *re* and *string.split()* you could do this:

```
import re
import sys

def word_count(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        text = infile.read()
        data = re.sub("(?<=[A-Za-z])[']+(?=[A-Za-z])", ' ', text)
        return len(data.split())

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(word_count(sys.argv[1]))
```